# How can I get code coverage from multiple projects

Tags: c#, tfs

I have a solution with 4 projects (2 regular and 2 test projects). I have a build pipeline in TFS 2018 that builds my solution and checks the code coverage. My problem is that only the code coverage from one project is reported. The code coverage from the other project is missing. All tests are run, though.

The Visual Studio Test step looks like this:

[image]

The relevant sections of the .runsettings file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RunSettings>
  <DataCollectionRunSettings>
    <DataCollectors>
      <DataCollector friendlyName="Code Coverage" uri="datacollector://Microsoft/CodeCoverage/2.0" assemblyQualifiedName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Coverage.DynamicCoverageDataCollector, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TraceCollector, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a">
        <Configuration>
          <CodeCoverage>
            <ModulePaths>
              <Include>
                <ModulePath>.*\.dll$</ModulePath>
              </Include>
              <Exclude>
                <ModulePath>.*CPPUnitTestFramework.*</ModulePath>
                <ModulePath>.*moq.dll</ModulePath>
                <ModulePath>.*Tests.dll</ModulePath>
              </Exclude>
            </ModulePaths>

        <!-- We recommend you do not change the following values: -->
        <UseVerifiableInstrumentation>False</UseVerifiableInstrumentation>
        <AllowLowIntegrityProcesses>True</AllowLowIntegrityProcesses>
        <CollectFromChildProcesses>True</CollectFromChildProcesses>
        <CollectAspDotNet>False</CollectAspDotNet>

      </CodeCoverage>
    </Configuration>
  </DataCollector>
</DataCollectors>
```

Here is the log output from the test step:

> 2018-11-19T13:19:41.2308934Z ##[section]Starting: VsTest - netframework
>   2018-11-19T13:19:41.2412211Z ==============================================================================
>   2018-11-19T13:19:41.2412390Z Task         : Visual Studio Test
>   2018-11-19T13:19:41.2412658Z Description  : Run unit and functional tests (Selenium, Appium, Coded UI test, etc.) using the Visual Studio Test runner. Test frameworks that have a Visual Studio test adapter such as xUnit, NUnit, Chutzpah, etc. can also be run. Tests can be distributed on multiple agents using this task (version 2).
>   2018-11-19T13:19:41.2412934Z Version      : 2.3.28
>   2018-11-19T13:19:41.2413056Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
>   2018-11-19T13:19:41.2413412Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=835764)
>   2018-11-19T13:19:41.2413616Z ==============================================================================
>   2018-11-19T13:19:42.4501863Z Run the tests locally using vstest.console.exe
>   2018-11-19T13:19:42.4502051Z ========================================================
>   2018-11-19T13:19:42.4502460Z Test selector : Test assemblies
>   2018-11-19T13:19:42.4502750Z Test assemblies : * * \release\ * Tests.dll,! * * \obj\ * *
>   2018-11-19T13:19:42.4503062Z Test filter criteria : null
>   2018-11-19T13:19:42.4503281Z Search folder : C:\agent_work\1\s
>   2018-11-19T13:19:42.4503610Z Run settings file : C:\agent_work\1\s\MyProject\CodeCoverage.runsettings
>   2018-11-19T13:19:42.4503933Z Run in parallel : false
>   2018-11-19T13:19:42.4504212Z Run in isolation : false
>   2018-11-19T13:19:42.4505649Z Path to custom adapters : C:\agent_work\1\s\MyProject\Project2Tests\bin\release
>   2018-11-19T13:19:42.4505955Z Other console options : null
>   2018-11-19T13:19:42.4506168Z Code coverage enabled : false
>   2018-11-19T13:19:42.4506699Z Rerun failed tests: false
>   2018-11-19T13:19:42.8500173Z VisualStudio version selected for test execution : toolsInstaller
>   2018-11-19T13:19:43.0554534Z ========================================================
>   2018-11-19T13:19:43.1339450Z [command]C:\agent_work_tool\VsTest\15.9.1-preview-20181023-04\x64\tools\net451\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform\vstest.console.exe @C:\WINDOWS\SERVIC~3\NETWOR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\c6857b51-ebfd-11e8-a1f3-554a7ebf3861.txt
>   2018-11-19T13:19:43.3385913Z Microsoft (R) Testausführungs-Befehlszeilentool Version 15.9.1-preview-20181023-04
>   2018-11-19T13:19:43.3451743Z Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten.
>   2018-11-19T13:19:43.3452021Z
>   2018-11-19T13:19:43.3612218Z vstest.console.exe
>   2018-11-19T13:19:43.3612440Z "C:\agent_work\1\s\MyProject\Project1Tests\bin\Release\Project1Tests.dll"
>   2018-11-19T13:19:43.3612731Z "C:\agent_work\1\s\MyProject\Project2Tests\bin\Release\Project2Tests.dll"
>   2018-11-19T13:19:43.3612945Z /Settings:"C:\agent_work\1\s\MyProject\CodeCoverage.runsettings"
>   2018-11-19T13:19:43.3613085Z /logger:"trx"
>   2018-11-19T13:19:43.3613289Z /TestAdapterPath:"C:\agent_work\1\s\MyProject\Project2Tests\bin\release"
>   2018-11-19T13:19:43.6746135Z Die Testausführung wird gestartet, bitte warten...
>   2018-11-19T13:19:44.9662159Z Microsoft (R) Coverage Collection Tool Version 15.0.30319.3000
>   2018-11-19T13:19:44.9663027Z
>   2018-11-19T13:19:44.9666782Z
>   2018-11-19T13:19:44.9674700Z Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>   2018-11-19T13:19:44.9677551Z
>   2018-11-19T13:19:50.3174860Z Bestanden Test1
>   ... lots of other tests ...
>   2018-11-19T13:19:53.3609732Z Microsoft (R) Coverage Collection Tool Version 15.0.30319.3000
>   2018-11-19T13:19:53.3610319Z
>   2018-11-19T13:19:53.3610430Z
>   2018-11-19T13:19:53.3610840Z Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>   2018-11-19T13:19:53.3611590Z
>   2018-11-19T13:19:53.8607813Z Bestanden Test2
>   ... more tests ...
>   2018-11-19T13:19:53.9355517Z Ergebnisdatei: C:\agent_work\1\s\TestResults\TFS-BUILD09$_TFS-BUILD09_2018-11-19_14_19_50.trx
>   2018-11-19T13:19:53.9358179Z
>   2018-11-19T13:19:53.9451115Z Anlagen:
>   2018-11-19T13:19:53.9470455Z   C:\agent_work\1\s\TestResults\332a54cb-163b-4b3b-9bd4-2f5a5be70f4e\TFS-BUILD09$_TFS-BUILD09 2018-11-19 14_19_44.coverage
>   2018-11-19T13:19:53.9591330Z
>   2018-11-19T13:19:53.9709295Z Tests gesamt: 128. Bestanden: 128. Fehler: 0. Übersprungen: 0.
>   2018-11-19T13:19:53.9741454Z Der Testlauf war erfolgreich.
>   2018-11-19T13:19:53.9781474Z Testausführungszeit: 8,6925 Sekunden
>   2018-11-19T13:19:54.2519255Z Publishing test results to test run '178'
>   2018-11-19T13:19:54.2519974Z Test results remaining: 128. Test run id: 178
>   2018-11-19T13:19:54.3272038Z ##[section]Async Command Start: Publish test results
>   2018-11-19T13:19:54.6094836Z Published Test Run : https://xxx/_TestManagement/Runs#runId=178&_a=runCharts
>   2018-11-19T13:19:54.6095328Z ##[section]Async Command End: Publish test results
>   2018-11-19T13:19:54.6096656Z ##[section]Finishing: VsTest

Comment: Look at the output of the test step. Are all the tests you're expecting to run being run? Update your question with the logs.

Comment: @Daniel Mann: Yes, all tests are run. I checked the log. I will update my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the answer.

In the Include section of the .runsettings-file, I had this:

```
<Include>
    <ModulePath>.*\.dll$</ModulePath>
</Include>
```

This means that only the .dll-assemblies are being evaluated. To also include the .exe-assemblies, you have to write the following:

```
<Include>
    <ModulePath>.*\.dll$</ModulePath>
    <ModulePath>.*\.exe$</ModulePath>
</Include>
```